# nimblekit failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a beginner ios developer making my app. I am using nimblekit on xcode 3.2.6. My app runs fine in the simulator when I try to run it on my iphone(ios 3.1) checking device instead of simulator in the overview menu, I get the error:

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

and just above it, named link with a grey exclamation mark is this:

```
ld: in /Library/Frameworks/libNimbleKit.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice for architecture armv6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your Xcode is not recognizing the arm6 information for the type of device you are using. I would recommend finding the support for Apple, but first, try uninstalling your xcode, and reinstall. then, if that doesn't work, find the support https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: Thanks! I have reinstalled xcode but now I get an error saying xcode could not find a valid provisioning profile, thats because I dont have one. I am planning to publish my app on cydia so I only need the .app file, do I really need to pay apple 99 dollars a year?, if the answer is yes then do I have pay to get the app just on my jailbroken iphone?

Comment: for a provisioning profile, you MUST have a devlopers license. It is required for any development testing, but for you to get it on your iphone, i believe so. Unless you are able to go the part that says device or simulator, go to device, and click in the menu "build" -> "build and archive", then just click share, and save it as the .ipa, and it should download through iTunes, if you cannot, then you must have a developer's license. I have never tried it without the license.

Comment: I believe you have to have a license for all things dealing with testing, downloading, and i know for sure posting the app on the app store, but I am sure you need the 99 dollar package in order to get it on your device. That is probably the best way to do things.